# Magento2 Quote Table to Order items table?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1

How **Magento** Copies data from **Quote** table to **Sales order items**?
If I want to save one field from **Quote** to **Sales order items** , Which files I need to change?

Comment: Do you mean Quote Item to Order Item Table ?

Comment: Magento save quote table to order table and quote_item table to order_item table

Comment: check file vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/fieldset.xml AND vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/fieldset.xml for available fieldset

Comment: i create one field in Quote table. Also create one field in sales_order_item table. i saved data in Quote table. from cart page"update cart" but i want saved data on that one field in magento sales order items table in magneto?

Comment: quote to order item table. 1 to many relation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Overview of converting a custom field from quote item to order item in Magento 2**

### Step 1: Add a di.xml file

### Step 2: Identify a code, a plugin

### Step 3: Add a class to your module, then identify a function

### Step 1: Add a di.xml file

In the module app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc, please add the di.xml file.
Step 2: Identify a code, a plugin

In the di.xml file, let’s identify a code:

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="HelloWorld_to_order_item" type="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Plugin\Quote\HelloWorldToOrderItem"/> </type>
```

Then, identify a plugin `Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Plugin\Quote\HelloWorldToOrderItem” of class “Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem`
Step 3: Add a class to your module, then identify a function

In the module, add the class Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Plugin\Quote\HelloWorldToOrderItem, and identify the function aroundConvert which will convert the custom data from quote item to order item at the same time.

```
public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        /** @var $orderItem Item */
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);
$orderItem->setCustomField($item->getHelloWorldCustomData());
        return $orderItem;
    }
```

Comment: This is for converting quote_item to order item. and it can be done by defining Fieldset in your custom module. you were asking for converting Quote field to to order item filed in your question.